# Is there a python wrapper covering multiple scholarly resources API endpoints?

Tags: citations, software, bibliometrics, online-resource, automation

**Question**: Does anybody know of a Python Wrapper containing a number of the [mentioned APIs listed by MIT](https://libraries.mit.edu/scholarly/publishing/apis-for-scholarly-resources/)?

**Context**: I want to execute a systematic literature review, and apply bibliometrics/ citation tracking and analysis by creating a citation graph and citation matrix.

**Tooling**: The toolchain at this moment is manual creation of BibTex files and then automated creation of the graph via bibgraph3. Bibliometrics then can be achieved via Bibliometrix and Biblioshiny.

The library of MIT has curated a nice list of relevant databases containing information on publications. This list in combination with Goodreads/ Worldcat would make it possible to create data-rich BibTex objects. MIT list included: arivm, CrossRef, DPLA, IEEE, Scopus, Web of Science and more. https://libraries.mit.edu/scholarly/publishing/apis-for-scholarly-resources/

This question is linked to: [Resources of APIs for automated paper citation aggregation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57489/resources-of-apis-for-automated-paper-citation-aggregation)
where the OP was looking for a source of recerences. I will manualy create txt files with the references per paper, and want to use the API's in a txt2bib script. And then feed this to the bib2graph.